# Model Fields in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am implementing a Custom User interface by adding two new fields in the built in User model.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

  is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_contractor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to create two new profiles based on the values in these two fields.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
  pass
class Contractor(models.Model):
  pass
```

if

> is_employee

is True then create an employee and if

> is_contractor

is True then create a contractor.

In django documentation django signals are used to create this link between models using pre_save and post_save function but how can I access the field value from the user model?

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this in your `signals.py`:

```
def create_employee_or_contractor(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    Contractor = apps.get_model('your_app', 'Contractor')
    Employee = apps.get_model('your_app', 'Employee')
    if created:
        if instance.is_employee:
            Employee.objects.create(....)
        else:  // or elif if you need a different logic
            Contractor.objects.create(...)

post_save.connect(create_employee_or_contractor, sender=CustomUser)
```